# Android: Low FPS drawing many bitmaps in a surfaceview

Tags: android, performance, surfaceview

I'm trying to create a bullethell game and Ive run into a bit of a trouble. I can't get more than 17 fps after about 500 bullets. The update logic code takes around 1-4ms for all of them while the render code takes around 40ms

For now my code is

```
private void drawEntities(Canvas canvas) {
    for (HashMap<UUID, Spatial> h: spatialList) {
        for (Spatial spatial: h.values()) {
            spatial.render(canvas);
            if(spatial.life > 0)
                spatial.life--;
            else if (spatial.life == 0)
                engine.deleteEntity(spatial.owner);
        }
    }
}
```

spatialList is an arrayList where each index is a zLevel

The spatial which displays the actual bullet is

```
public void render(Canvas canvas) {
    float angle = (float) (vel.getAngle() * (180 / Math.PI));
    matrix.reset();
    matrix.setTranslate(pos.x - bullet.getWidth() / 2, pos.y - bullet.getHeight() / 2);
    matrix.postRotate(angle + 90,  pos.x, pos.y);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bullet, matrix, paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(pos.x, pos.y, col.getRadius(), paint);
}
```

I can provide more code but these seem to be the main issue. I've tried everything I can think of and can't find much else online. The only thing I can think of to fix this is to switch from a surfaceview to a GLSurfaceview but I really think there is a better way and I'm just using bad code.

Edit: I noticed my timer was off and removed the drawcircle and after running it again I get 40ms~ around 500 which is still a bit too low for reasonable performance.

TLDR; 500 entities = 17 fps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be limited by pixel fill rate.  How large (in pixels) is the display on your test device?

One simple thing to play with is to use [`setFixedSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceHolder.html#setFixedSize(int,%20int)) to reduce the size of the SurfaceView's Surface.  That will reduce the number of pixels you're touching.  Example [here](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/HardwareScalerActivity.java#L259), video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpRaD-ij2xc), blog post [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/09/using-hardware-scaler-for-performance.html).

It's generally a good idea to do this, as newer devices seem to be racing toward absurd pixel counts.  A full-screen game that performs all rendering in software is going to struggle on a 2560x1440 display, and flail badly at 4K.  "Limiting" the game to 1080p and letting the display scaler do the heavy lifting should help.  Depending on the nature of the game you could set the resolution even lower with no apparent loss of quality.

Another thing to try is to eliminate the `drawBitmap()` call, check your timings, then restore it and eliminate the `drawCircle()` call, to see if one or the other is chewing up the bulk of the time.

You may find switching to OpenGL ES not so bad.  The "hardware scaler exerciser" activity in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika) (from the video linked above) shows some simple bitmap rendering.  Replace `drawCircle()` with a scaled bitmap and you might be most of the way done.  (Note it uses SurfaceView, not GLSurfaceView, for GLES in that activity.)

Comment: With just the drawCircle the fps does not drop below 30 on up to 750 entities on even my crappy phone which is awesome. However I have noticed that even with nothing being drawn the render time is 16ms which is wierd. The setFixedSize() function didnt see a tiny bit of increase in fps.  And youre saying you can use surfaceview for gles? interesting

Comment: Could be bitmap rotation. If you just drop `matrix.postRotate()`, do things improve? GLSurfaceView is just a wrapper class for SurfaceView that handles EGL setup and manages a renderer thread for you. Grafika has everything you need for EGL setup, and I'm guessing you're already managing your own threads for SurfaceView, so it might be straightforward (some GLES work required). A "render time" of 16.7ms could be due to queue-stuffing on a 60fps device, as SurfaceView does not drop frames; cf. https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#loops

Comment: Holy Moly, OpenGL is intimidating but since it does a speed increase and the transition doesnt seem too bad, Ill say say you answered it

Comment: Most of what you need is in Grafika or examples like Android Breakout (https://github.com/fadden/android-breakout) -- the latter being intended as an example of a simple but complete GLES 2.x game. I think the class composition in Grafika is better. Once you get past the initial learning cliff you're just blitting bitmaps. The one awkward area is text rendering, which you can do with a font texture (like Breakout uses) or for a score overlay just draw it on the View part of the SurfaceView.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The problem will be solved to a large extent if you do all the drawing on a bitmap framebuffer and then draw the framebuffer to the canvas. If you are directly drawing on the canvas then there are several overheads. I looked around and found this tutorial 
"http://www.kilobolt.com/day-6-the-android-game-framework-part-ii.html"

Look at the implementation for AndroidGraphics and AndroidFastRenderView and see how he uses AndroidGraphics to do all the actual drawing in a buffer and paints that buffer to the canvas in AndroidFastRenderView.

Comment: I am getting over 30 fps on most phones with 2 fullscreen background images, around 200 sprites with rotation and scaling, and with 32bit images.

Comment: Yeah, after using the framebuffer I could draw around 800 with minimal drop. The technique sure isnt easy to understand, easy to implement though.

Answer (score 0):

Try the performance when you remove the rotate and/or drawCircle parts from your render() method. Both of them might be quite time consuming as they probably contain sin() / cos() calculations.

If that helps, you'll have to figure out how to replace them with something faster, if not, well...

Comment: I have tried both of those and while they speed it up just a bit, the rotate is neccessary. The image needs to be dynamically rotated every frame to match the firing angle

Comment: I see, sorry it didn't help. I'm no game developer myself, so I'm afraid that was all I could offer :-/

Comment: I'm no gamedeveloper myself but for a bullethell 250 bullets is fairly limiting. It also hints that something is really slowing down my code.